# Scroll bar not displaying all content

Tags: html, css, iframe

I’m somewhat of a newbie with HTML and CSS, trying to replicate a more 90s CSS style by using iframes for a simple test site I’ve been working on recently. However, the text that I’m attempting to display within the iframe is always cut off, despite a scroll bar being coded in and visible. The scroll only adjusts a short way and doesn’t allow you to see the full contents of the text. Please advise. I’m sure I’ve made a simple error that you’ll notice in a few seconds, thanks in advance!

My html for the index (iframe and base)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pen and Parchment</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
    <body>
<div id="mapp">
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://img.nickpic.host/5woiL6.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="my homepage" title="my homepage" href="/home.html" coords="616,500,655,507,683,513,688,494,639,481,610,476" shape="poly">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="about me" title="about me" href="/about.html" coords="600,535,648,535,683,545,695,526,637,515,611,511" shape="poly">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="who i'm showing off right now" title="who i'm showing off right now" href="/showing.html" coords="613,559,685,571,691,555,613,543" shape="poly">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="my whole crew" title="my whole crew" href="/crew.html" coords="608,588,680,597,677,581,607,567" shape="poly">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="what's coming next" title="what's coming next" href="/plans.html" coords="600,618,671,626,667,607,602,599" shape="poly">
    <area target="_pnp" alt="your way outta here" title="your way outta here" href="/links.html" coords="595,653,664,656,664,636,600,631" shape="poly">
</map>

<div id="cont"><iframe width="500px" height="260px" name="_pnp" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="/home.html"></iframe></div>
<div id="bernard"><img src="https://img.nickpic.host/5wv65b.png"></div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  position:fixed;
  }
  
#mapp {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 300px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  
  }
  
#cont {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  top: -630px;
  left: 150px;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: clip;
  }
  
  #bernard {
  height: 245px;
  width: 196px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  top: -830px;
  left: 472px;
  z-index: 3;
    
    
  }
  
#text {font-size:12pt; color:#000; font-family: courier, serif; z-index: 10; padding-bottom: 10px; min-height:250px; height:100%}
#text img {max-width:500px;}
#text h1 {text-align:center;font-size:25pt;border-bottom:1px solid #819176;color:#a7b487;text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #819176;margin-top:-15px; letter-spacing:3px;}
#text h2 {font-weight:normal;text-align:center;font-size:20pt;letter-spacing:-1.5px;color:#8A906E;text-decoration:underline;}
#text a {text-decoration:none;color:#a7b487;}
#text a:hover {font-style:italic;}
#text b {font-size:10pt;letter-spacing:0.5px;}
#text i {font-size:12pt;}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  }
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #EFEFEC;
  }
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000;
  }
```

And then then HTML that I’m trying to get to show on the main page (within the iframe)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pen and Parchment</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <div id="text">
    <h1>W E L C O M E </h1>
<p> to <b>Pen and Parchment</b> a site catalogging the various pets and goings-on of various catz, dogz, horzes, and hexiez projects. I'm Ink - the proprietor and owner of PnP, and we're happy to have you here. As always, please excuse any construction mess. </p>
<center><p> Don't know what <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petz">Petz</a> is? <br>
check out these resources and forums for more information! Welcome to the Petz Community<br>
<a href="http://petzforum.proboards.com/" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/BGMtdL9/petzforum-banner-tiny.gif"></a> <a href="http://whiskerwick.boards.net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/F3WSBCJ/wwbeach.gif"></a> <a href="https://www.petzuniversal.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/kSZK6YJ/pugzlink.png"></a> <a href="http://seeingstars.boards.net/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/b7YJbyz/sy-Sikuum-o.png"></a> <a href="http://petzkennelclub.co.uk/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/JqMV9dr/23-PJyih-I-o.png"></a> <a href="https://tfm.petzcommunity.org/index.php?page=home" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/t8KHSWr/3-Ivdp-Oj-G-o.png"></a> <a href="https://discord.gg/f4SmVgh" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/q9mQ0YL/Petzcord.png"></a>

I don't play babyz myself, but if you think that might be your cup of tea, feel free to also check out:<br>
<a href="http://milkbc.proboards.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/jzPHv27/1-UFYIsl0-o.png"></a><br>
for more information!</p></center>
<p>
<h2> recent updates:</h2>
<p><b>06.20.21</b> PnP is officially back up and running! While the dust settles, please excuse the site changing a fair bit. </p>

</div></div>
</html>
```

Edit: thanks for editing my grammar, and not helping with the question, I guess...

Comment: Sorry, but using `position:fixed;` on  `body` doesn't make much sense, but will rather lead to problems. Also the large negative margins you are using will hide part of those elements, i.e. move them out of the visible area. I would erase all that...

Comment: @Spectric home.html is the third section of code I have at the bottom there, that's what is being displayed within the iframe.